# Can a file be deleted from Github without cloning whole repo (repo size is above 20 gigs)?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a huge repo, and we want to delete a file without cloning it in Jenkins and then committing the change?

We tried looking for any Github APIs but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: If it is from the last commit of a branch, then do a shallow clone: `git clone --depth=1 some-repo-url`.

Comment: You could do a partial clone, using `filter=`, of just the file you want to delete. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---filterltfilter-specgt

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Oh, that's cool! Even better, shallow with filter :-)

Comment: Note that adding a new commit that lacks the file doesn't actually *delete* the file, it just adds a new commit that does not have the file in it. A shallow clone of any commit that doesn't have the file won't bring over the file, but a full clone that brings over all commits, including the earlier ones that *do* have the file, will need the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#delete-a-file) for this.

```
curl \
  -X DELETE \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/contents/PATH \
  -d '{"message":"my commit message","committer":{"name":"Monalisa Octocat","email":"octocat@github.com"},"sha":"329688480d39049927147c162b9d2deaf885005f"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use GitHub Codespaces for that. In GitHub web UI: create a branch, then under the big green Code button switch from Local to Codespaces tab, and run.

You'll launch a remote dev environment in the browser, with VS Code and a terminal, and then it's business as usual: `rm <filename>`, `git add`, `git commit`, `git push`. Create and merge PR.